# Cart product staying even after removing it form the cart

Tags: java, android

I have this following activity class. This is the shopping cart class where product gets added to or removed from it. The operation works fine, however i am having a strange issue with it. The problem starts whenever i delete all the products from the cart and go to another activity and return back to the cart activity irrespective of adding or removing  items from the cart there is always a product left inside the cart. every time I remove that particular item it shows that it is removed and product disappears from the cart but when i return back again i find that single removed product staying in the cart. I can't find out the cause of this. Somebody please help me with this.

```
public class Secondscreen extends Activity {


private Context mContext;

int total = 0;
ArrayList<Listitem> arrayList = new ArrayList<Listitem>();
BaseAdapter adapter = null;

@Override
public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondscreen);
    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    // TextView showCartContent = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.showCart);
    final TextView showtotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.totalprice);


    final Button thirdBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.third);
    Button addmorebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.moreitems);


    final Controller aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

    int cartSize = aController.getCart().getCartSize();

    // initialize product variables and add item objects to the arraylist


    if (cartSize > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i < cartSize; i++) {

            String pName = aController.getCart().getProducts(i)
                    .getProductName();
            int pPrice = aController.getCart().getProducts(i)
                    .getProductPrice();
            int pQuantity = aController.getCart().getProducts(i)
                    .getProductQuantity();
            String pDisc = aController.getCart().getProducts(i)
                    .getProductDesc();
            // int pID =aController.getCart().getProducts(i).getId();

            // total calculated
            total = total + (pPrice * pQuantity);

            Listitem item = new Listitem(pName, pPrice, pDisc, pQuantity);
            Log.e("quantity", "" + pQuantity);
            Log.e("Intem's quantity", "" + item.getQuantity());
            arrayList.add(item);
            Log.e("Arraylist item quantity", ""
                    + arrayList.get(i).getQuantity());

        }
        showtotal.setText("" + total);

    }

    adapter = new BaseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arrayList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        @Override
        public View getView( final int position, View view,
                ViewGroup viewgroup) {
            if (view == null) {
                view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pattern, null);
            }
            TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nameview);
            TextView tv2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.pdesc);
            TextView tv3 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.priceView);
            TextView tv4 = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.quantityView);
            Button btn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.patternButton);

            // Remove button actions
            btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int tempstore = arrayList.get(position).getPrice();
                    int tempstore2 = arrayList.get(position).getQuantity();

                    //calculation of total
                    total = total - (tempstore * tempstore2);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    showtotal.setText("" + total);

                    ModelProducts tempProductObject = aController
                            .getProducts(position);
                    //
                    // int pID =aController.updateProduct(position).getId();
                    // Log.e("buttonid", ""+pID);
                    // aController.removeButtonId(position).getId();

                    aController.getCart().removeProducts(tempProductObject);
                    arrayList.remove(tempProductObject);
                    arrayList.remove(position);

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                    // FirstScreen obj=new FirstScreen();
                    // obj.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    // int cartSize = aController.getCart().getCartSize();


                }

            });

            tv.setText(arrayList.get(position).getName());
            tv2.setText("" + arrayList.get(position).getPrice());
            tv3.setText(arrayList.get(position).getDesc());
            tv4.setText(String.valueOf(arrayList.get(position)
                    .getQuantity()));

            return view;
        }

    };
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    // int cartSize2 = aController.getCart().getCartSize();
    if (cartSize == 0) {

        Log.e("emptycartmethod", "I am in empty cart sate");

        aController.getCart().getCartlist().clear();
        // Intent intent = new Intent(Secondscreen.this, FirstScreen.class);
        // startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    // Third Button Action

    thirdBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Thirdscreen.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

    // AddMoreItem Button Action

    addmorebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();

  }
}
```

Comment: Every time does it hold only one value in the cart - on clicking back button or sometimes even more than one.?

Comment: Every time it hold only one value in the cart-on clicking back button and surprisingly even after closing the app by clicking the back button and restarting it again i find that single product still staying in the cart.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to store the quantity in the bundle. during the rebuilding of the Activity you can get the data from the Bundle and set the correct value inside the oncreate method using getSavedInstanceState.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I appreciate it. but i am having problem with the product staying in the cart and i am not able to find the source of this problem. somebody please help me

Comment: please add the removeProducts code (any details can help)